# vue build crashes ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ubuntu, npm, vue-cli

I have created an app which is built with nodejs and vue2. In the development process everything works fine and the testing server (npm run serve) makes no problem at all. Even the build runs on my local machine (MacBook with M1 chip) without a problem but when I try to run the build process on Ubuntu the system starts hanging and needs to be rebooted. I also had occasions where the build process started a fork pump and the server had to be shut down from the provider dashboard.

I got the following output on the console before the system got stuck:

```
-  Building for production...
/usr/local/bin/node[4781]: ../src/node_platform.cc:61:std::unique_ptr<long unsigned int> node::WorkerThreadsTaskRunner::DelayedTaskScheduler::Start(): Assertion `(0) == (uv_thread_create(t.get(), start_thread, this))' failed.
 1: 0xa24ed0 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0xa24f4e  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0xa9588e  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0xa95956 node::NodePlatform::NodePlatform(int, v8::TracingController*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x9f3416 node::InitializeOncePerProcess(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x9f3651 node::Start(int, char**) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x7fd84016bbf7 __libc_start_main [/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6]
 8: 0x98293c  [/usr/local/bin/node]
```

I then only got the following message in the terminal.

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily
```

I'm on a Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0 x86_64) with the following specs:

- CPU vCores    6
- RAM guaranteed    16 GB
- Storage space 300 GB

The command `ulimit -u` returns `62987` which from my understanding should be good.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error can be the ulimit - your server, or to be more precise the user that executes the build job, does not have enough resources available.
You can check it with `ulimit -u` and raise it with `ulimit -u 1024`.

Comment: with the command `ulimit -u` I receive 62987. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: I updated my question with the server specs.

Comment: Ok yes that should be enough. Sorry to hear this didn't solve tbe issue for you.